# Diagram between Sheaves Commutes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $(f, f^\#): X \to Y$ a morphism between schemes, therefore $f: X \to Y$ between underlying topol spaces and $f^\#:\mathcal{O}_Y \to f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ sheaf morphism. Let $s \in \Gamma(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)$ be a global section. Obviously $s$ corresponds uniquely to a sheaf morphism, denoted by $\hat{s} : \mathcal{O}_Y \to \mathcal{O}_Y$.

My question is why the following diagram commutes:

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
f^* \mathcal{O}_Y  @>{f^* \hat{s}}  >> f^* \mathcal{O}_Y   \\
@VVV  @VVV   \\
\mathcal{O}_X @>{\widehat{f^\#(s)}}>> \mathcal{O}_X 
\end{CD}
$$

Remark: Vertical arrows are canonical isomorphisms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you really too lazy to check that the diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A \otimes_B B  @>{a \otimes b \mapsto sa \otimes b}  >> A \otimes_B B   \\
@V{a \otimes b \mapsto \varphi(a)b}VV  @VV{a \otimes b \mapsto \varphi(a)b}V   \\
B @>{\cdot \varphi(s)}>> B 
\end{CD}
$$
commutes for a ring map $\varphi: A \to B$?

Either path sends $a \otimes b$ to $\varphi(s)\varphi(a)b$.

Comment: Haha, sorry, in light of commutative algebra the question seems indeed ridiculous. The problem was to translate the morphism $f^* \hat{s}$ to the ring side.